# How to modify on to be sargable- sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query

```
update r
   set Comp = t.Comp
from [QlikDataWarehouse].[dbo].[Vente]r
 inner join
     [QlikDataWarehouse].[dbo].[Budget] t
     on t.[Code Site] = r.[Code Site] and
        t.[Code Rayon] = substring(r.[Code Structure],1,4) and
        t.[Date Time] = convert(date,r.[Date Time])
where r.[Date Time] >= '2015-01-01 00:0:00.000';
```

nmber of rows of budget is around 800000 and vente around 350+millions rows .
I create index `vente([Date Time], [Code Site], [Code Structure])` and `Budget([Code Site], [Code Rayon], Date Time])`. But the query took days running .

`t.[Code Rayon]` is an int type 
`t.[Date Time]` is a date type
`r.[Date Time]` is datetime type 
Is there a way to make clause On sargable ?

Any help would be the most appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried using the query plan to see where the performance hits are, hopefully being able to identify something like a large table scan that is occurring?

Comment: What's the query plan? How many rows there are in total in both tables? Is Code Site + Core Rayon + Date Time unique?

Comment: Bad news. I think no way without refactoring..

Comment: Your index doesn't include comp? Is that causing a key lookup?

Comment: Check the query plan before jumping to conclusions

Comment: You're trying to update 350 million rows with one update? Maybe you should split it up into smaller pieces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want this to be sargable, then add computed columns and indexes on them.

```
. . . 
from [QlikDataWarehouse].[dbo].[Vente] r inner join
     [QlikDataWarehouse].[dbo].[Budget] t
     on t.[Code Site] = r.[Code Site] and
        t.[Code Rayon] = substring(r.[Code Structure],1,4) and
        t.[Date Time] = convert(date,r.[Date Time])
where r.[Date Time] >= '2015-01-01 00:0:00.000';
```

To handle the join:

```
alter table Vente add code4 as (left([Code Structure], 4);
alter table Vente add datecol as cast([Date Time] as date);
create index idx_vente_4 on Vente([Code Site], code4, datecol, [Date Time];
```

And write this part of the query as:

```
from [QlikDataWarehouse].[dbo].[Vente] r inner join
     [QlikDataWarehouse].[dbo].[Budget] t
     on t.[Code Site] = r.[Code Site] and
        t.[Code Rayon] = code4 and
        t.[Date Time] = datecol
where r.[Date Time] >= '2015-01-01 00:0:00.000';
```

To filter the data before the `join`:

```
alter table Vente add yyyy as (year([Date Time]) 
create index idx_vente_4 on Vente(yyyy, [Code Site], code4, datecol, [Date Time];
```

Then write this part of the query as:

```
from [QlikDataWarehouse].[dbo].[Vente] r inner join
     [QlikDataWarehouse].[dbo].[Budget] t
     on t.[Code Site] = r.[Code Site] and
        t.[Code Rayon] = code4 and
        t.[Date Time] = datecol
where r.yyyy = 2015;
```